# Implement map into application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I would like to ask if there is any free solution ready to implement it to my application? I'm aiming into Open Street Map as I want free solution. I know about OsmSharp which is neat but lack of documentation and there is a question:

is there possibility to change for example pin design or map layout?
I heard that it's possible but you have to write your own render...

I am targeting iOS, Android and WP with our geolocalisation game app.

Answer (score 4):

Xamarin Forms has a built in [Map](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/maps/) control.  [TKCustomMap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TK.CustomMap/) is a third-party renderer that adds functionality to the built in map.

Comment: Yes, but Map control is built only for Google Maps from what I know? Is it possible to put there Open Street Maps, add some nice filter to make it looks good and that's it?

Comment: No, the Forms Map control renders as a Native Map (Google, Bing, Apple) on each respective platform.

Comment: Okay, but if my app will generate bigger traffic, then Google or other vendor will shut down my API key and app will stop working. That's why I want to use OSM on all platforms. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: there is a Xamarin friendly port of OSM - http://www.osmsharp.com/.  I have no idea how/if it works with Forms, or if you would have to write custom renderers.

Answer (score 0):

About leak documentation I have written a blogpost about it: http://zchpit.blogspot.com/2017/10/open-street-map-in-xamarin-forms.html

You can find source code on my github: https://github.com/zchpit/OPM_in_XamarinForms

About:
is there possibility to change for example pin design or map layout?

Yes. You can change map (one from many) or generate your own map (same like in standard xamarin)

Answer (score 0):

As with other OSM library/framework solutions, you will need to provide your own tile server or use a commercial OSM tile service.

> Mapsui is a C# map component for apps
>
> Supported platforms: WPF, UWP, Android, iOS

- https://github.com/pauldendulk/Mapsui

Comment: Its not good at all and I don't recommend it to anyone else. Lack of good documentation (almost nothing just a quick start) and they sample codes its not working anymore since code changes in new versions. so kinda your on your own without a good help.